# How to prevent input value to be submitted in form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I have an `ASP.Net Application` with simple `WebForms`. There are some pages which are used to insert and update the records in the database.

But, in some cases some input control values should not be updated. So, I have set the `disabled` attribute to prevent user to update the value. But, user can also enable it from the developer tool and change the value directly.

If I remove the `name` attribute from the element using `javascript` then the value of that control will not be submitted in the form and it won't be affected at server side *(It works perfectly)*. But, if user reassigns the same vaule (*i.e.* `'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$txtBranchCode'`) in `name` attribute then the value of the input box will be submitted again *(That should not be happend)*.

**Code:**

```
<td align="left">
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$txtBranchCode" type="text" value="HO" 
         id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_txtBranchCode">
</td>
```

**Now, what I want is if I can prevent the element value to be submitted in the form then my problem can be solved easily.** I cannot add the condition in every page *"if the control is disabled then it should not be updated."* There are lots of pages and I have to do the same work in each and every page. If there is common solution then it would be better.

Comment: The only safe and secure way to do this is on the server. You need to check if that value should be used and ignore it if not. Anything done on the client can be changed as you've already stated.

Comment: Yes @webnoob I know server side validation is better but, I cannot modify all pages, its too many. So, I am trying to find a common solution. If I could unregistered control from the asp form so, Asp Form does not post value of that control.

Comment: Not only better - the only safe way. If you are facing this issue now with the architecture, you are likely going to face it again in the future. Why is the same logic having to be done in many places? Could you not condense some functionality to a base class / service that can do this validation for you? I understand it might mean a lot of work to introduce but it depends how much of a requirement this is.

Answer (score 0):

You can not trust the client side code to control the updates in database.
what you should do is to write some server-side code to do the job. The client side code can be easily manipulated by clients and you can not trust it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where input control value should not be updated, don't render the control by setting `Visible="false"`.

Server side validation is more secure whereas client side validation provides a better user experience, so there is a trade-off. Ideally both should be in place, better user experience with client side validation and protect server resources and databases with server side validation.

Comment: I cannot make the control invisible. User can see the values of control but, should not be allowed to edit it. There are lots of pages in my application So, I cannot place the condition to update the value if control is enabled for every page.